# Selenium ChromeDriver Error: uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::By

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nokogiri, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click an element with Selenium Webdriver and ChromeDriver:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "nokogiri"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://twitter.com"
driver.findElement(By.className("StreamsLogin")).click();
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::By
```

The element is definitely there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the way you are trying to find the element is Java code. For Ruby try this:

```
driver.find_element(:class, "StreamsLogin").click
```